# If '' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, module, angular9

I am working on an Angular 9 project. As long as the project was growing, I decided to split code into feature modules. I've created a separate feature module, declared and exported every child component. I've also imported the feature module in the AppModule.

After running `ng serve`, I still have this error : `If 'app-component-name' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.` (The error occurs on every single component used in my feature module, resulting in dozen of error line with the same message.)

Here's a snippet

**landing-page.module.ts**

```
//Core imports
...

//Lib imports
...

//Routing
import { LandingPageRoutingModule } from './landing-page-routing.module';

//Shared components
...

//Components
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page.component';
import { SectionCompositionLayoutComponent } from './section-composition/section-composition-layout/section-composition-layout.component';
import { SectionPresentationLayoutComponent } from './section-presentation/section-presentation-layout/section-presentation-layout.component';
import { SectionContactLayoutComponent } from './section-contact/section-contact-layout/section-contact-layout.component';
import { SectionDescriptionLayoutComponent } from './section-description/section-description-layout/section-description-layout.component';
import { SectionHeaderLayoutComponent } from './section-header/section-header-layout/section-header-layout.component';
import { SectionLocationLayoutComponent } from './section-location/section-location-layout/section-location-layout.component';
import { SectionPricesLayoutComponent } from './section-prices/section-prices-layout/section-prices-layout.component';
import { SectionProximitiesLayoutComponent } from './section-proximities/section-proximities-layout/section-proximities-layout.component';
import { CompoDetailsComponent } from './section-composition/compo-details/compo-details.component';
import { CompoTotalComponent } from './section-composition/compo-total/compo-total.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './section-header/header/header.component';
import { InfobarComponent } from './section-header/infobar/infobar.component';
import { CallToActionComponent } from './section-presentation/call-to-action/call-to-action.component';
import { ExtraCardComponent } from './section-prices/extra-card/extra-card.component';
import { PricesTabComponent } from './section-prices/prices-tab/prices-tab.component';
import { CardDistanceComponent } from './section-proximities/card-distance/card-distance.component';
import { NearComponent } from './section-proximities/near/near.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LandingPageComponent, 
    SectionPresentationLayoutComponent, 
    SectionCompositionLayoutComponent, 
    SectionContactLayoutComponent, 
    SectionDescriptionLayoutComponent, 
    SectionHeaderLayoutComponent, 
    SectionLocationLayoutComponent,
    SectionPricesLayoutComponent, 
    SectionProximitiesLayoutComponent,
    BouncingIconComponent,
    BtnContactComponent,
    FlagComponent,
    SeparatorComponent,
    CompoDetailsComponent,
    CompoTotalComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    InfobarComponent,
    CallToActionComponent,
    CarouselComponent,
    ExtraCardComponent,
    PricesTabComponent,
    CardDistanceComponent,
    NearComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LandingPageRoutingModule,

    //Libs imports
    ...
  ],

  exports: [
    LandingPageComponent, 
    SectionPresentationLayoutComponent, 
    SectionCompositionLayoutComponent, 
    SectionContactLayoutComponent, 
    SectionDescriptionLayoutComponent, 
    SectionHeaderLayoutComponent, 
    SectionLocationLayoutComponent,
    SectionPricesLayoutComponent, 
    SectionProximitiesLayoutComponent,
    BouncingIconComponent,
    BtnContactComponent,
    FlagComponent,
    SeparatorComponent,
    CompoDetailsComponent,
    CompoTotalComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    InfobarComponent,
    CallToActionComponent,
    CarouselComponent,
    ExtraCardComponent,
    PricesTabComponent,
    CardDistanceComponent,
    NearComponent
  ],
  
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
})
export class LandingPageModule { }
```

**landing-page-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: LandingPageComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LandingPageRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
//Core imports
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


//Lib imports
...

//Core Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

//Feature modules
import { LandingPageModule } from './landing-page/landing-page.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],

  imports: [
    //Core imports
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    //Libs imports
    ...

    //Feature module imports
    LandingPageModule
  ],

  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./landing-page/landing-page.module').then(m => m.LandingPageModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

After reading docs and toturials, I can't find the reason why it isn't working. I tried to `npm update/install` and `ng serve` again but still not working. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you add the html where `app-component-name` is used? Or do you know which component uses it in its template?

Answer (score 12):

Few things which should be clarified:

- if you import your module in AppModule, this module becomes a part of your main bundle and will not be loaded lazily. (You should not add your LandingPageModule to AppModule if you want to load it lazy)
- If you get error `If 'app-component-name' is an Angular component...`, this means that you don't have this component in scope of the module where you get this error. You can get the component available in the module within 2 ways: add this component to `declarations` or import module which exports this component.
- If you want to use some component in few lazy loaded modules, you should move this component to [shared module](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) and import this module to every module where you need this component.

So if you want to split your app with lazy loaded modules you should be sure that:

1. All your modules have declared or imported all required components.
2. All your lazy loaded modules joined to your app module only with routing.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, if would be easier to debug the issue if you can share a link to your code in stackblitz or in some other way.

Based on what code you have shared, it appears that you have both imported and lazy loaded the feature module into **app.module.ts** and **app-routing.module.ts**. you can do either one of them but not both at the same time

Comment: I removed the import in the AppModule because I want the feature module to be lazyloaded. After serving again, the same problem occurs. 

I'll try to provide a stackblitz to make this easier to debug.

Comment: I made this Stackblitz to help debugging. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dmjtrh

But after reading answers and apply these to the stackblitz project, it seems to work now.